# Can I get the base URL of my Rack service outside of a request handler?

Tags: ruby, rack

I'd like to be able to retrieve the base URL of my web app from within the Rack initialization code in my `config.ru`.  Something along the lines of:

```
puts "Starting up on http://#{ENV['SERVER_NAME']}:#{ENV['SERVER_PORT']}/#{ENV['MOUNT_POINT']}..."
```

but I haven't found anything like this that's available from outside of a request handler.  Obviously, I can do something like:

```
...
def get
  puts "Got a request for #{ENV['rack.url_scheme']}://#{ENV['HTTP_HOST']}#{ENV['REQUEST_PATH']}"
  ...
```

because the request is defined at that point.  But at the start of my config file, none of those variables appear to be defined.

Is there a Rack method I can use to access this information?  Is this one of those cases where those things aren't finalized until Rack startup is finished?  I seem to remember other frameworks having a way to pass a proc to a method that will execute it once the environment is "ready". Does Rack have anything like that?

Comment: What are you trying to set in the config.ru that needs this information?

Comment: I'm not trying to *set* anything, I just think it's nice for the log to show where the service is -- it's especially useful when a new dev tries testing for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible for a Rack application can know ahead of time the "mount point".  For example, this `config.ru` mounts the same app at multiple mount points:

```
require 'rack'

app = proc { |env|
  [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['hello, world!']]
}

run Rack::URLMap.new('/myapp' => app,
                     '/' => app)
```

Rack also does not provide any standard method that is called at initialization time.  I suspect this is because Rack tries to support plain CGI, where a whole Ruby process may be created to handle each request, with the process exiting at each request.  In that situation, there isn't much use for an "init" method.

Answer (score 2):

It's about a year later but I was just struggling with the same problem and found your thread.

Every Rack application provides a call-method that gets called by the Rack handler. For example see the code of Sinatra::Base#call. This call method gets called once per request and has one parameter which is a hash that contains environment variables. Within these there is everything you need and the "mount_point" you were asking for is called "SCRIPT_NAME".

See http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/file/SPEC for details. Unfortunately this information is only available to you during a request and not before as far as I know. Hope it helps others.